# Не удается исполнить комманду apt-get

Tags: linux, debian

Прошу помогите, установил себе линукс на микрокомпьютер, при использовании apt-get выскакивает ошибка, с чем может быть связяно?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease\
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports InRelease
Err http://opensource.nextthing.co jessie InRelease
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://http.debian.net jessie-backports Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
Err http://opensource.nextthing.co jessie Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'opensource.nextthing.co'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.nextthing.co/chip/debian/repo/dists/jessie/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.nextthing.co/chip/debian/repo/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'opensource.nextthing.co'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Попробуйте `ping 208.67.222.222` . Если пинг пройдет то копайте в сторону настроек DNS если нет то у Вас просто нет доступа в интернет

Comment: @Fisherman пишет что неизвестный хост

Comment: Тогда разбирайтесь с подключением к Интернет. Вы его вообще настраивали?

Comment: @Fisherman Я подключаюсь по ethernet кабелю, но инета нет, в чем может быть дело

Comment: Так. Давайте тогда подробней. 1.) Сиситема, как я полагаю судя по репам, debian в чистом виде. 2.) Дайте в вопрос вывод `ifconfig -a` или `ip addr` и `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. 3.) И самое главное "link" на сетевухе горит если там есть лампочка? Если нет лампочки на сетевухе гляньте на свитче. 4.) Что за "микро-компьютер"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на этом компьютере у вас нет доступа к сети «[интернет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)».

**как** настроить — вопрос весьма обширный. можете начать с какого-нибудь руководства «для чайников», из первых строчек запроса «название-вашего-дистрибутива настройка сети».

например, первое попавшееся, [с картинками](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-seti-debian-9).